# Trying to extract json object from JSONArray

Tags: java, json, gson, objectmapper

This is my JSONArray Structure

```
{
"docs": [
    {
        "_index": "junit",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "2003",
        "_version": 1,
        "found": true,
        "_source": {
            "data": "\"year\":\"2003\"",
            "name": "2003",
            "type": "year",
            "ancestors": [
                "PARTS"
            ],
            "child": {
                "year_make": [
                    {
                        "name": "Honda",
                        "id": "2003_Honda"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "junit",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "2003_Honda",
        "_version": 1,
        "found": true,
        "_source": {
            "data": "\"year\":\"2003\", \"make\":\"Honda\"",
            "name": "2003_Honda",
            "type": "year_make",
            "ancestors": [],
            "child": {}
        }
    }
]}
```

And this is the java object I want to convert the response to

```
public class PartsNode extends Node {

   @Id
   String id;
   ...
}
```

The class above extends this abstract class

```
public abstract class Node {

   String name;

   List<String> ancestors = new ArrayList<>();

   String type;

   Map <String, Set<ChildInfo>> child = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   String data;
}
```

I am trying to do something like this

```
 private List<T> translateResponseToNodes(String responseBody, Class<T> classType) {
    List<T> nodes = new ArrayList<T>();
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(responseBody)) {
        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONArray jsonArr = responseJson.getJSONArray("docs");
        int length = jsonArr.length();

        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            JSONObject jObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            JsonElement data = (JsonElement) jObj.get("_source");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            T node = gson.fromJson(data, classType);
            node.setId(jObj.get("_id").toString());
            nodes.add(node);
        }

    }

    return nodes;
}
```

Currently I am taking the input classtype to determine the type of the Node. Assuming there should be some better way to do this.

Comment: How should the program know which type to use unless you specify a class?

Comment: that is why I am passing the classType for now.

Comment: Sounds OK I'd say

Comment: I think I also see an issue with the nested ChildInfo object here. Gson doesn't seem to normalize that one.

Comment: Are you just trying to extract all `_source`s with `_id` from parent? I am not sure if I understood correct but why you need to have those instantiated as different `classType`s?

Comment: Well there is no real question here.